# Missing ), ], or Item in query expression

Tags: database, vb.net, winforms, forms, ms-access

Not sure why I'm getting this error, I had a look online but couldn't find a solution that worked, any ideas?

I am attempting to search for user's via products, so I enter in a product name and the user's full name and address will be output to a listbox, when I type in a product, however, I get this error:

Missing ), ], or Item in query expression '(((CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName) = 'Red Apple''.

I asked a question previously about the same program which helped a lot with my syntax but I guess I'm still not quite there, I'm still learning SQL so sorry if it is something really simple! :)

```
Dim searchDatabase As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("SELECT CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName, CustomerAccountDetails.custAddress " _
                                                         & "FROM (CustomerAccountDetails " _
                                                         & "INNER JOIN CustomerTransaction ON CustomerAccountDetails.ID = CustomerTransaction.custID) " _
                                                         & "INNER JOIN (StockDescription " _
                                                         & "INNER JOIN TransactionDetails ON StockDescription.ID = TransactionDetails.stockID) ON CustomerTransaction.ID = TransactionDetails.custTransID " _
                                                         & "WHERE(((CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName) = '" & productSearch & "'", databaseConnection)
```

Dim searchResults As OleDbDataReader = searchDatabase.ExecuteReader

Comment: I think `& "WHERE(((CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName) = '" & productSearch & "'`(see your's `'" & productSearch & "'"` )

Comment: Can you check the number of parenthesis, I see you have 2 open '(' parenthesis and have not closed it

Comment: Woops, I didn't even notice that aha, If I fix that I still get the same error though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, I fixed it and it was a parenthesis error but when I fixed it I got another error which said "mismatch error" so I assumed that I hadn't fixed it, silly me! In the end the mismatch error was because I had my primary keys declared as the wrong variable type and the correct syntax for the parenthesis was this.

& "WHERE CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName = '" & productSearch & "'" _
                                                             & "ORDER BY CustomerAccountDetails.custFullName, CustomerAccountDetails.custAddress; ", databaseConnection)